# Vue - add v-on directice in generated html code

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

In my vue project i'm using google map api and over marker icons i generate infoWindow with custom html code.
I that code I would like to add in  tag *v-on:click* listener. Every my try failed, always vue generate it as html.

My code

```
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:  '<div class="listing-box">\n' +

                        '        <div class="listing-rate-share">\n' +
                        '            <div class="rated-list">\n' +
                        '                <b class="la la-star"></b>\n' +
                        '                <b class="la la-star"></b>\n' +
                        '                <b class="la la-star"></b>\n' +
                        '                <b class="la la-star-o"></b>\n' +
                        '                <b class="la la-star-o"></b>\n' +
                        '                <span>(13)</span>\n' +
                        '            </div>\n' +
                        '            <span><i class="la la-share-alt"></i></span>\n' +
                        '           <a href="#" title="" '+v-on:click="this.addRemoveFavorite(place)"+'><i class="la la-heart"></i></a>' +
                        '        </div>\n' +
                        '    </div>' });
```

Ho to add this part **on:click="this.addRemoveFavorite(place)"** correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 2 approaches that will help you to achieve such a functionality, with cleaner templates and better code:

Constructor of `google.maps.InfoWindow` [accepts also DOM node](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add), so you can create component with your code and then pass `ref` of it to `InfoWindow` constructor.

Another way is to use [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps).